# Adjust WooCommerce price if product is picked from specific archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm not sure if this is possible, but it feels like it should be.

I have a list of products that I wish to display via two different archives (set by another plugin) where I can control the products displayed by listing categories with the shortcode.  The different archives need to have different prices showing for the same products and sometimes to not list specific products within a category.

So what I've done is setup categories (which are filterable on the front end and as such display their name) with the same name but different slugs for each archive page and then added each product to both categories with the same name so they show up in each archive.

The problem is I need to increase the base price of almost all of the products in one archive by 0.50 and I can't figure out a way of doing it.  I can achieve the correct result visually like this:

```
function bbloomer_alter_price_display( $price_html, $product ) {

global $wp_query;
$slug = basename(get_permalink($wp_query->post->ID));

// Only if not null
if ( '' === $product->get_price() ) return $price_html;

  // If on specifc archive page   
  if ( $slug == "eathere" ) {
    $orig_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $price_html = wc_price( $orig_price + 0.50 );
  }

return $price_html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_alter_price_display', 9999, 2 );
```

But obviously, this only updates the visual price, and as soon as it's added to the cart and checkout it just shows the base price, unaltered.

I know that you're supposed to update the cart separately with a hook like `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` but I can't figure out how to apply the logic that it has to have come from this archive to have the modified price.

This code works for the category they're in:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_sale_price_for_category', 10, 2 );
function custom_sale_price_for_category( $price, $product ) {

  //Get all product categories for the current product
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $categories[] = $term->slug;
  }

  if ( ! empty( $categories ) && in_array( 'eathere-burgers', $categories, true ) ) {
    $price *= ( 1 + 0.50 );
  }

  return $price;
}
```

But this will then affect the prices across the site regardless of which archive page they're on.  If I add that it should only affect the archive page via the slug as in the first example then they appear correctly in the archive but again don't change in the cart of checkout.

I'm really stuck on how to get this working without duplicating the entire product list and adjusting the price.  It feels like this should be possible with a simple bit of code but WooCommerce's hooks and filters are so dense in their functionality I'm finding it hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the logic is correct or not but you can try with Session Variable in 'woocommerce_product_get_price' filter to store value of archive

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["archive"] = "eathere";
```

Now get the same session variable value on cart/checkout Hook 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' & don't forgot to
`session_start();` & get value of `$_SESSION["archive"]` in this hook to check archive slug & update the price according to that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not familiar with session variables but your logic seems to hold up.  Could you elaborate on the suggested usage please?  I've had a little play and I can't seem to get any results using it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code assign slug value to session variable in if & elseif statement based on which archive page you are on

```
function bbloomer_alter_price_display( $price_html, $product ) {

global $wp_query;
$slug = basename(get_permalink($wp_query->post->ID));

// Only if not null
if ( '' === $product->get_price() ) return $price_html;

  // If on specifc archive page   
  if ( $slug == "eathere" ) {
$_SESSION["archive"] = "eathere";
    $orig_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $price_html = wc_price( $orig_price + 0.50 );
  }
elseif ( $slug == some_other_archive_slug ) {
$_SESSION["archive"] = some_other_archive_slug;
    $orig_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $price_html = wc_price( $orig_price + 2 );
  }

return $price_html;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_alter_price_display', 9999, 2 );
```

on Cart/Checkout page compare the value of archive page slug with Session variable slug value & based on that update the price of the product

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'update_price_cart', 9999 );
 
function update_price_cart( $cart ) {
 
 
    // LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS & ADD Price
if ($_SESSION["archive"] == "eathere"){
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price + 0.50 );
    }
}
elseif ($_SESSION["archive"] == some_other_archive_slug) {

$product = $cart_item['data'];
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price + 2 );

}
 
}
```

Sometimes it may give error in that case you need to start_session(); before assigning value to session

Comment: Ah, I'm with you!  I wouldn't have thought to try it that way.

It almost works, the only issue is that the mini cart is showing the modified price in the totals but not on the items, so it looks like there's a hidden charge being added.  eg. item £7.50 Subtotal £8.00.

Is there a standard hook for mini cart items or is this going to be more specific to the plugin generating it?

Comment: Mini cart hooks depends on theme & Plugins used mostly. Can you please try to update the price of the product based on session in this filter as well - 'woocommerce_cart_item_price'

Comment: I found one more hook - 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity' 
I think this will work because it's specific for mini cart from woocommerce

Comment: Hi bud, adding either of those hooks in stops the product from arriving in the cart I'm afraid.  I've also noticed that if I increase the quantity above one using the cart quantity buttons the subtotal revets to the calculating with the original price.  So close and yet so far!

Comment: oh, that should not happen unless the $_session value is changed or it's empty. can you please check what is the $_session value by echoing ( "echo $_SESSION["archive"];" ) just before if statement in "update_price_cart" function ? the value will be displayed on cart page & in this way you can verify if still session variable has the archive page slug.
if it's not displaying any value then can write session_start(); just before if statement within "update_price_cart" function.
Please let me know if it works or give any error

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough with that last comment, by cart I meant the mini cart.  It sits next to the product list on the archive page and when items are added they appear in it straight away via ajax.  Those hooks are stopping this functionality.  As far as I can tell the session is holding fine as if I go through to the checkout then it's all correct, it's just the mini cart.

Comment: Hi, this filter will definitely work 'woocommerce_cart_item_price' even i tried but sometimes the price is getting disappeared. I've added the filter within foreach loop & returned price value. even you can run this filter separately........... I tried below code..................
 add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', function($price,$cart_item, $cart_item_key){
         
            echo $price;
            $price = $cart_item['data']->set_price( 10 );
            return $price;}, 10, 3);   ................. if it works you can apply same logic of session here.